# Solving I. y[n+2]-(1/3)y[n+1]=sin(n) and II. y[n+2]+3y[n+1]-4y[n]=n-1 difference equations

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have two difference equations, which I just can't solve. I hardly even get the method, so if you could help me with the steps, I would be grateful.

1. $y_{n+2}-\frac{1}{3}y_{n+1}=\sin(n)$
2. $y_{n+2}+3y_{n+1}-4y_{n}=n-1$

Answer (score 0):

at first solve the equation
$y_{n+2}+3y_{n+1}-4y_n=0$ with the ansatz $y_n=q^n$

Comment: I get q=1 or q=-4. How to continnue?

Comment: thus your solution is $y_n=C_1+C_2(-4)^n$

Comment: to find a special solution for the inhomogeneous equation is difficult

Comment: Where can I find some kind of good description?